# Etimologia del toponimo "Paderno"

Tags: etymology, toponyms

Qual'è l'etimologia del toponimo "Paderno", che è abbastanza diffuso nell'Italia nord-orientale?  Ad orecchio direi "paterno", ma sarei felice (chi si contenta…) di saperne qualcosa con certezza.

Segue lista, da [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paderno)

Paderno d'Adda – comune della provincia di Lecco
Paderno Dugnano – comune della provincia di Milano
Paderno Franciacorta – comune della provincia di Brescia
Paderno Ponchielli – comune della provincia di Cremona
Paderno del Grappa – frazione del comune di Pieve del Grappa in provincia di Treviso
Paderno – frazione capoluogo del comune di Ponzano Veneto in provincia di Treviso
Paderno – frazione di Premariacco in provincia di Udine
Paderno – frazione di San Gregorio nelle Alpi in provincia di Belluno
Paderno – quartiere di Udine
Paderno – quartiere di Paderno Dugnano in provincia di Milano
Paderno – frazione di Bologna
Paderno – frazione del comune di Mercato Saraceno in provincia di Forlì-Cesena

Comment: [Una cosa che so per certa](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paderno_Dugnano#Storia), Paderno è una frazione di Paderno Dugnano in quanto il comune di Paderno Dugnano fu creato raggruppando i paesi di Paderno Milanese e di Dugnano, più altre frazioni, nel 1869, anche se il nome attuale  fu adottato solo nel 1886.

Comment: @Hachi Per favore posta quello che hai scritto come risposta e non come commento. I commenti servono solo per suggerire miglioramenti alla domanda.

Answer (score 0):

Il toponimo “Paderno”, origine quasi certamente latina del nome “Paternus”, deriva dall'aggettivo “paterno”, che in epoca romana stava ad indicare i fondi derivanti dalle eredità.

Comment: Potresti dare qualche fonte sul nesso tra il termine latino e i toponimi attuali?